# Помогите выбрать лучший вариант для заполнения списка

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, form

Встал вот такой житейский вопрос:
Есть форма: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В которой если я слева выберу категорию, то справа соответственно хочу выбрать 1 из списка. Если слева тэг  , думаю суть вы поняли.

Но, как лучше с точки зрения архитектуры развернуть это задание, чтобы не было overhead реализации?

Как пример, вот что у меня есть сейчас:

- Сохранить на контроллере в сессию/куки обьекты, и их на вьюхе через jQuery onChange рендерить
- В отдельный скрытый див вынести значения, и доставать их через jQuery с него
- Вытянуть ajax запросом в первый раз все значения, и записать их в глобальную переменную, с которой и будет идти выборка в дальнейшем

Все 3 варианта мне не нравятся, попахивает нехорошо, и я надеюсь, что вы подскажете мне решение/инструмент, который может решить качественно эту задачу.

P.S мой стек технологий(PHP + JS/jQuery)

Спасибо)

Comment: Почему бы не вытягивать Ajax запросом каждый раз нужный список?

Comment: чем плох создать двумерный массив JS: var categoriesArr = new Array();
var categoriesArr = new Array();
categoriesArr[1] = new Array();
categoriesArr[1][0] = 'Category 1';
categoriesArr[1][1] = 'Item 1';
categoriesArr[1][2] = 'Item 2';
categoriesArr[2] = new Array();
categoriesArr[2][0] = 'Category 2';
categoriesArr[2][1] = 'Item 1';
categoriesArr[2][2] = 'Item 2';

Comment: Владимир Клыков - здесь используется multi input, и на 20 форм мне нужно будет сделать минимум 40 запросов, что как вы понимаете, не здорово.

Comment: Kosmos, прежде чем в массив что-то записать, нужно что-то достать из БД. В вашем случае если я правильно понял +1 в сторону варианта 3, только с записью в assoc array, верно ?

Comment: @AlexKhonko, не важно, как положите в массив. Более того, из условий задачи не понятно, каким именно образом он формируется. Можете сразу при генерации страницы в PHP генерировать этот JS массив. Уж тем более не вижу смысла в данной задаче использовать Cookie.

Comment: @Kosmos как мне передать данные в скрипт в вашем случае? Для примера, возьмём 3 простых SELECT. Ок, я получил массив обьектов БД. Как их передать в JS?

Answer (score 1):

Благодарю @Kosmos за наводку.
Итак, мне нужно было единожды передать данные в скрипт js, чтобы в ситуации, описанной выше, и вот такой вот картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при выборе слева entity, справа получить его список.
Провернуть проще всего(с разделение логики работы приложения) оказалось вот так:

**На стороне контроллера:**

```
# 1  создаю нужные мне массивы( именно массивы, с обьектами так просто не заехало)
        $users = User::find()->asArray()->all();
        $cats = Category::find()->asArray()->all();
        # ........
        # 2 передаю всё в вид:
        return $this->render('index2',[
            'users' => $users,
            'cats'  => $cats,
            # ....
        ]);
```

**На стороне вьюхи:**(данный скрипт должен появится раньше того, что будет работать с переменной)

```
<script>
var users = <?=json_encode($users)?>
var cats = <?=json_encode($cats)?>
</script>
```

Скрипт, который будет закреплен после сможет работать с моими переменными, и при этом я делаю ровно 1 запрос при загрузке страницы, который можно спокойно закешировать, в результате чего 1 запрос на несколько сотен/тысячь вызовов страниц

**After Party**: пока делал, столкнулся с тем, что с select -> option через $(this).val() я буду получать номер entity. Для ещё большей понятности кода сделал вот такой трюк:
**В моделе:**

```
const PREFERS_CATEGORY = 0;
const PREFERS_TAG = 1;
const PREFERS_AUTHOR = 2;
```

**В контроллере:**

```
$jsData = [
            UserPrefers::PREFERS_AUTHOR => $users,
            UserPrefers::PREFERS_CATEGORY  =>$cats,
            UserPrefers::PREFERS_TAG  => $tags,
        ];

        return $this->render('index2',[
            'jsData'    => $jsData,
            #...
```

Во вьюхе ничего не поменялось, выводим мою переменную, а затем в обрабатывающем скрипте я делаю вот так:

```
$('.form-group > select').on('change',function () {
console.log(jsData[$(this).val()]);
```

});

Вместо лога делаем что угодно с уже рабочим массивом, всем добра)